# Creating Query in MS-Access, but part of Query is being returned at zeros?

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm attempting to create a query of multiple inventories, essentially I'm pulling together every item and certain information on it. However the "ID" (which is an Autonumber) on one of the databases won't format correctly.

SELECT Format([ID], "J0"), [Date Deployed]
FROM databaseJetPacks
UNION ALL
SELECT Format([ID],"T0"), [Date Deployed]
FROM public_tablets;
UNION ALL
SELECT Format([ID], "S0"), [Date Deployed]
FROM tableSwitches

[Screenshot of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geZlZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format string is the issue - you're attempting to format an `Integer` as a `String`. Try using the `CStr()` function on the `Integer` to convert it first.

```sql
SELECT 'J' & CStr([ID]), [Date Deployed]
  FROM databaseJetPacks

 UNION ALL

SELECT 'T' & CStr([ID]), [Date Deployed]
  FROM public_tablets

 UNION ALL

SELECT 'S' & CStr([ID]), [Date Deployed]
  FROM tableSwitches
```